# Which is better to send e-mail using .net or trigger in the SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

We have this module where user can register and they need to confirm their e-mail address.

Currently I used .NET to send e-mail. So after adding the record I will now call my email method. But what I noticed is there are times that the e-mail functionality does receive a timeout error and since I catch all the exception this error is presented to the user.

What I wanted is to send the e-mail on the background. If there are any mail connection timeout, the e-mail method will just retry sending the e-mail for probably a minute or two.
And I'm thinking of using the SQL mail to achieve this. But I'm not sure if its the best solution.

Comment: personally I'd keep it out of the database - it's not a database problem. Maybe kick it off in a new thread that runs seperate to the user thread. Also are you presenting the standard .net error page or a custom one? If so, check this out: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/04/67-of-aspnet-websites-have-serious.html

Comment: You are right that sending e-mails should be handled by .NET. Well I'm using the standard error page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use [SQL Server Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to perform the heavy lifting around the email queuing and sending. The application would still be responsible for constructing the message and sending it to the database. Relay through a separate SMTP server (installing SMTP services directly on a SQL machine is probably not a good idea).
2. Use [async email methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) from your web application, e.g. `SmtpMail.SendAsync()`. This will allow you to handle errors without holding up the user (or interacting with the user), but it's not durable. If your web process restarts, the operation is lost.
3. Use a Windows service. This will be a simple, separate application which simply monitors the database for new email tasks and/or is sent a message from the web application that a task needs to be performed.

Option #2 using `SendAsync()` will be the quickest to implement. Depending on your needs, that may be sufficient.

Option #1 shouldn't require much more effort. Option #3 really shines when you need to implement complex business logic around the recipient list and the email contents. It's also possible to combine options #1 and #3 (see the conversation between @RemusRusanu and me in the comments).

With both option #1 and #3, if the environment goes down, a service restarts, or an error occurs, you won't have lost any data or failed to send an email.

Comment: Does it mean that I will have a seperate table where I will log the list of e-mail notifications which my service will scan on schedule. :)

Comment: If you go that route, yes. Doesn't have to be anything complicated, just the recipient, content, and a status indicating if it has been sent or not.

Comment: SQL Server comes with [a service that does exactly that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887(v=sql.105).aspx), why advocate writing your own?

Comment: @RemusRusanu - Good question. I've only used database mail for sending mail to specific, pre-configured email profiles. I'm not sure how well it supports pulling in a dynamic list of email addresses (such as might be encountered in a normal web app). I'm also not sure of how configurable the output emails are, e.g. if you could create an email template customized to match your website. Lastly, a more complex service might incorporate business logic. All of these things very well might be possible with database mail--I would be interested to see an answer demonstrating that.

Comment: Database Mail will handle asynchronous delivery of the email (pickup the email from DB, connect to SMTP, send). It is not purposed for composing emails (eg. templates). The job of composing the email (templates, MIME includes, A/B choices, etc) would fall onto the application, but once composed it can just drop off the mail for Database Mail to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Rather manage the time-out in the .net application.  If there is an issue or a time out in the trigger your data may not be committed.  Rather allow the DB to complete the data transaction, and check the state from your .net App.

I dont think there is a definitive answer to this, but this would be my preference.